# Clojure: how to check you are in instarepl?

Tags: clojure

How to check in clojure module whether it's running from LightTable instarepl or from `lein run`?

Answer (score 0):

Asking questions about the runtime environment seems like a fragile thing and not something I'd ordinarily recommend - I'm curious what you're trying to do.

I don't know instarepl, but lein appears to [set environment variables](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L488) that you should be able to check for